Unable to filter out and refresh feed from an firebase query
I am using firebase for the data querying. I am using a pagedlistview and a controller in order to create an infinite list. And this list generates items, that can be filtered through a filter. The filter option updates the app state, and what I am trying to do is make the listview listen to the app state, then filter the data based off it, and refresh with the new data once the filter has been selected, so it shows the new items that have been filtered through the options.
Right now it is only filtering due to MaxNum due to me testing it. It all loads whenever no filters are applied. But when anything is filtered, then it returns no items. And the listview does not refresh when app state gets changed. Here is the code:
class FilteredVenturesListView extends StatefulWidget {
  const FilteredVenturesListView({
    Key? key,
    this.width,
    this.height,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final double? width;
  final double? height;

  @override
  State<FilteredVenturesListView> createState() =>
      _FilteredVenturesListViewState();
}

class _FilteredVenturesListViewState extends State<FilteredVenturesListView> {
  final PagingController<int, VenturesRecord> _pagingController =
      PagingController(firstPageKey: 0);

  final int _numberOfVenturesPerRequest = 10;
  bool _isLoading = false;
  final appState = FFAppState();

  void _listenForAppStateChanges() {
    appState.addListener(() {
      _pagingController.refresh();
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _listenForAppStateChanges();
    _pagingController.addPageRequestListener((pageKey) {
      _fetchPage(pageKey);
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pagingController.dispose();
    _listenForAppStateChanges();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _refreshListView() {
    _pagingController.refresh();
    // _fetchPage(0);
  }

  Future<void> _fetchPage(int pageKey) async {
    if (_isLoading) {
      return; // Already loading, do nothing
    }
    _isLoading = true;
    Query? venturesQuery; // Declare venturesQuery here

    if (appState.maxPeople == -1) {
      // Check for -1 (unlimited)
      final venturesQuery = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('ventures')
          .orderBy('created_time')
          .limit(_numberOfVenturesPerRequest);
    } else {
      final venturesQuery = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('ventures')
          .where("maxNum",
              isEqualTo: appState.maxPeople) // Corrected field name
          .orderBy('created_time')
          .limit(_numberOfVenturesPerRequest);
    }

    if (pageKey > 0) {
      final lastDocumentSnapshot =
          await _pagingController.itemList?.last?.reference.get();
      if (lastDocumentSnapshot != null && lastDocumentSnapshot.data() != null) {
        final lastCreatedTime = lastDocumentSnapshot.get('created_time');
        venturesQuery?.startAfter([lastCreatedTime]);
      }
      _isLoading = false;
    }

    final venturesSnapshot = await venturesQuery?.get();
    final OldVenturesList = venturesSnapshot?.docs
            .map((doc) => VenturesRecord.fromSnapshot(doc))
            .toList() ??
        [];

    final venturesList = OldVenturesList?.where((venture) {
      return ((appState.maxPeople == -1 ||
              venture.maxNum == appState.maxPeople) &&
          (appState.ventureCountries?.isEmpty ??
              true ||
                  appState.ventureCountries!.contains(venture.destination)) &&
          (appState.ventureIndustries?.isEmpty ??
              true || appState.ventureIndustries!.contains(venture.industry)) &&
          (appState.ventureMonth == 'Empty' ||
              venture.startingMonth == appState.ventureMonth) &&
          (appState.minWeeks == -1 || venture.minLength >= appState.minWeeks) &&
          (appState.maxWeeks == -1 || venture.maxLength <= appState.maxWeeks));
      // return true;
    }).toList();

    final isLastPage = venturesList?.length ?? 0 < _numberOfVenturesPerRequest;
    if (isLastPage) {
      _pagingController?.appendLastPage(venturesList);
    } else {
      final nextPageKey = pageKey + 1;
      _pagingController?.appendPage(venturesList, nextPageKey);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PagedListView<int, VenturesRecord>(
      pagingController: _pagingController,
      builderDelegate: PagedChildBuilderDelegate<VenturesRecord>(
        itemBuilder: (context, venture, index) {
          return VenturesWidget(
            key: Key(
                'Keyqg1_${index}_of_${_pagingController.itemList?.length ?? 0}'),
            ventureRef: venture.reference,
            userRef: venture.creator!,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

I have tried using different types of listviews - but I want to use infinite scroll with pagination so that it limits the amount of queries that it does to reduce the number of the firebase reads.
I have tried using a function to refresh the listview whenever app state gets changed. By using a function that tried to compare the old widget value with the new value then using a refresh.

"there still happen to be errors" What errors? And rather than including them in a comment, please edit your question to include this information.
